# Mysql compare json column with array

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, phpmyadmin

I'm working on a PHP PDO query and I want to check if a JSON column intersects with a PHP array.

```
$classes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];
|---------------------|------------------|
|      students       |       classes    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      [1,3,6]     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          13         |     [2,9,10]     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          14         |     [9,8,10]     |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

for example in the example above i need to get all student with at least one classe exist on the `$classes = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7];` array so in this case the result should be :

```
|---------------------|------------------|
|      students       |       classes    |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          12         |      [1,3,6]     |
|---------------------|------------------|
|          13         |      [2,9,10]    |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

I tried to make the array as a string and do a "%like%" but it not working because of `'x,y,z'` is not in `'a,b,x,c'`.

so I was wondering if we can compare two arrays on stored in MySQL as json and the other is a PHP array. and I need to do that inside the query.

thanks

Comment: So you want to compare two array ?

Comment: yes, two arrays on stored in MySQL as json and the other is a PHP array. and i need to do that inside the query

Comment: Can you please show some example data and the code ? Also the expected output

Comment: @executable i don't need to compare just two php arrays , check my comment i edited the question to explain more , thanks anyway

Comment: Do  you mean `$json_column = "['x','y','z']";` instead?

Comment: get the JSON from the database, deserialise it to a PHP array, and then compare the data. Why do you think you "need" to do it in the query exactly? All you'd be doing then would be comparing two strings,which doesn't do anything to help you match the actual data items within the strings.

Comment: @ADyson  check my updates

Comment: Ok. The problem here is that your data is de-normalised. You should be storing the list of classes in a separate table, where each class ID is in a separate row of the table with a foreign key back to the student. If ever you find yourself storing multiple values in a single field like this, then you know you've made a mistake in your database design. If you design it in a properly normalised way then the query you're wanting would just involve a JOIN and a simple `IN` clause in the WHERE section.

Comment: (P.S. Using JSON fields are fine for some arbitrary snippet of information you just want to store there and retrieve, but not for things which are part of the actual structure and querying of your data, such as this)

Comment: Yes, @ADyson I agree with you that the data is denormalized. but in my case, I found the data like this and it will be a big challenge to normalize it and make all refactoring, so I was thinking to this as a bypass, but it still nice to have a function in such situation.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `JSON_EXTRACT` ([link](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_extract/))?

It should let you treat it as an array.

[DigitalOcean HowTo](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/working-with-json-in-mysql) (I am not affiliated with them in anyway).